# Refused to execute script because its MIME TYPE

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Vue.js` on a `LEMP Stack 16.04`. My site is using a `Let's encrypt` certificate.

My assets are compiled with `Laravel Mix` and inserted in my application

```
<script src="{{mix("/js/manifest.js")}}"></script>
<script src={{mix("/js/vendor.js")}}></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

#### Situation

When I go to `https://example.com`

> Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/js/app.6fb8b055657fe5daae8f.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

[image]

The file `app.6fb8b055657fe5daae8f.js` type is `text/html` but there is another call whose initiator is `app.6fb8b055657fe5daae8f.js` and whose type is `script`. Don't know if this is normal

#### Questions

Is that normal MIME Type is recognized as `text/html` whereas it is my `app.js` file ?

What can I do to make it work ? Is it a issue with `nginx`or `laravel` or `SSL Certificate ?

#### nGinx used (custom compile)

```
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --add-module=/home/leo/ngx_brotli --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --add-module=/home/leo/ngx_pagespeed-1.12.34.2-beta --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads
```

#### example.com.conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

#server {
 # server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;
  #root www/laravel/public ;
#}


server {

        # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com *.example.com www.example.com ;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

          location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

#### nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/ja$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/mime.types

```
types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    ............
    ............
}
```

Comment: Javascript / .js should be Mime-Type: text/plain. Perhaps you can force a Mime-Type header to be send. I know how to do this in PHP, but not in JS.

Comment: what is your nginx configuration?

Comment: @Tamar I added the details

Comment: do you have js in your /etc/nginx/mime.types?

Comment: @Tamar Yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code first.

```
<script src="{{mix("/js/manifest.js")}}"></script>
<script src={{mix("/js/vendor.js")}}></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

It's even highlighted in your question, now check this one:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and see if this helps.

Comment: There was indeed a problem with my `git push` and the file was not on the server